# Is it necessary to use a uniform distribution in the probabilistic method?

Tags: probability, probabilistic-method

In the probabilistic method, I often see we define a sample space and sample the elements of the sample space uniformly at random and use it to prove something exists. For example, in the proof of a lower bound of a Ramsey number, if $\binom{n}{k}2^{1-\binom{k}{2}}<1, R(k,k)<n.$
We start by assuming each edge is colored with probability $0.5$ for each color (blue or red).

What if we do not use the uniform distribution? We'll get a new valid result or results that are unrealizable in practice? Is it necessary to stick with the uniform distribution?

I expect that a non-uniform distribution should be as fine if we try to show the probability of something is non-zero, as long as you do not give too many zero probabilities to realizable objects (e.g. a graph with all red/blue edges). But for the expectation argument in the probabilistic method, I think if you use non-uniform distributions, all expected values could be changed and we could get a weaker or stronger statement than its counterpart theorem that assumes a uniform distribution.

I try to find the discussion on this issue on various resources, but couldn't find it yet.

Comment: In general, assuming things are chosen uniformly random is an assumption you make which is motivated by the system you are working with. Whether that assumption is valid or not depends on the situation

Comment: Yes, of course. Think of the probabilistic method like taking an integral transform, like Fourier transform. You extract information about the original problem, from the transform. All sorts of weights can be useful.

Comment: Consider the possible values of two six-sided dice being rolled. It's easy to see that $2$ should be less common than $7$ so a uniform distribution would be incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

In fact the [second example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_method#Second_example) of the Wikipedia article on the probabilistic method uses a non-uniform distribution. By including each potential edge in a graph on $n$ vertices with probability $p=n^{1/g−1}$, it proves that for large $n$ the probabilites for the graph to contain at most $n/2$ cycles of length less than $g$ and to contain no independent set of size $\left\lceil\frac n{2k}\right\rceil$ are both greater than $\frac12$, and thus there must be a graph that has both of these properties.

Comment: Thanks! Does this means there is nothing special about using uniform, right? (and you could get useful conclusion from non-uniform as well)

Comment: @STN: It does mean that, yes.